# Travel from Tatranska Lomnica to Krakow city centre

Tags: trains, buses, poland, slovakia, tatras

We are going from Tatranska Lomnica to Krakow.

Preferably with train, but we're open for suggestions. We hope to avoid going through Poprad, as this would be a detour.
We would like to do as much as possible by train, so that we change from bus to train when we cross the border, if possible. 
Most important: not too long as we are traveling with a toddler.
What is the best way to do this?
As for the bus part of the journey, do the bus companies provide baby seats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did a bit more research and decided for bus to Zakopane, operated by www.strama.eu, departs Tatranska Lomnica 4 times a day.
We then took the Train from Zakopane to Krakow.
The total amount of time was a bit longer than only bus, but we wanted to keep the bus leg as short as possible.

Answer (score 1):

[TigerExpress](http://www.tigerexpress.eu/) runs direct minibuses. Neither they, nor their parent company [LEO Express](http://le.cz), have information on car seats on their websites.

If you want to take the train, you could take this bus to Nowy Targ and change to a train there. The total journey world take longer and cost a bit extra.